# ajax, json send data from one php file to another and then send the data back

Tags: ajax, json

Trying to send (with ajax,json) data from file No1 to file No2 and then from file No2 send data to file No1

Here is code in file No1

HTML

```
<div id="first_var">1 one</div>
<div id="second_var">2 two</div>
<div id="load"></div>
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var one = $("#first_var").val();
var two = $("#second_var").val();
var dataString = 'one='+first_var+'&two='+second_var;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'fileNo2.php',

data: dataString,
dataType: "json",

success: function(data) {
$('#load').html(data);
}
});
```

Here is file No2

```
$p_one = $_POST['p_one'];
$p_two = $_POST['p_two'];
$test = $p_one. '<br>test<br>'. $p_two;
echo json_encode($test);
```

As a result in `<div id="load"></div>` see only word `test`

If instead of `data: dataString,` use `data : { p_one: 'test 1', p_two: 'test 2' },` then everything works.

Possibly incorrectly definied `var one` etc? Seems `var one = $("#first_var").val();` `val()` can be used if `<div id="first_var">1 one</div>` would be input field. But if it is not input field? Simply text inside `id="first_var`....

Please, advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to name the keys correctly in the data string.  The PHP script is expecting "p_one" and "p_two", not "one" and "two".

```
var dataString = 'p_one='+first_var+'&p_two='+second_var;
```

Also, you need `.text()`, not `.val()` to get the inner text:

```
var one = $("#first_var").text();
```

Comment: Yes, sorry my negligence again... changed one example and have not paid enough attention. Now partly works. in `<div id="load"></div>` get `[object HTMLDivElement]` instead of `1 one` and `2 two`

Comment: @user2465936 maybe a couple more problems ... for one, you need `.text()` instead of "val".